# How to let RubyMine work with cygwin64

Tags: ruby, windows, rubymine, jetbrains-ide

I'm currently using **cygwin64 on my Windows 10** virtual machine. On there, I've installed **rvm**, and the default (and only) version of Ruby is **ruby 2.4.0p0**. Through my IDE (**RubyMine**) I've **linked the ruby interpreter to the ruby interpreter installed on my cygwin64 installation**. However, there are some **issues** i'm having which are quite annoying and I though I would ask here for anyone who might have had this issue before and fixed it some how.

The issues are:

- Gems not found (requiring files are 'not found': including the standard library, methods not found, classes not found, ...)
- Using `cmd` I cannot use commands such as `bundler`, `gem` etc (I have to use the cygwin64 terminal)
- Some features on RubyMine don't work (including the Run button, etc)

I've thought about path variables, but I don't really know which ones I have to set (and where to).

Any help would be appriciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to get some things working today and I though I might aswell share it here, for anyone having similar issues in the future. I fixed the first issue through setting up a **ssh server** on my **cygwin64** installation and allow localhost connections to it. I then set up a **'remote interpreter'** through **RubyMine** and linked it to the ruby interpreter through the ssh connection. Gems are found, RubyMine no longer complains about unknown files, code completion works, for me a success!

I then went searching a bit and found a alternative for the `cmd` not allowing commands such as `bundler`, `gem`, etc. I didn't fix it, but I managed to **link the RubyMine's terminal to my cygwin64 terminal**. I now can execute these commands through RubyMine, so that isn't that bad.

Setting up the remote interpreter:
File -> Settings -> Languages & Frameworks -> Ruby SDK and Gems

Linking the terminal:
File -> Settings -> Tools -> Terminal -> Shell path -> C:\cygwin64\Cygwin.bat (in my case)